# How to run multiple jars in single docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, jar

Is there a way to run multiple **jars** in a **single docker container** as sub-services of let's say a server API or sould i split them in multiple containers and manage them by some scheduler ??

Comment: Hey Mark, This is an open ended question and doesn't really fit the nature of these boards. We ask that you try to build something yourself and then ask questions about it when you get stuck with a specific code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A typical setup would be to run only one application in a container, and for the containers to run network services; so run a long-running container for each of your Java backends, with an HTTP service, and in the Node proxy make an HTTP call to the appropriate backend.  That doesn't require anything Docker-specific in the application.

Comment: i edited the question so its focusing on the choise i am facing thanks for the feedback and  sorry if any frustration occurred, i'm new at the community